# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'prependTo'

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I know there's a lot of these questions out there, but none of the answers fixed my issue. Here's the things I have tried/validated with no result.

Also, here's the page offending: http://sandboxdewsly.com/author/tomclark/
(You must select "galleries" and then choose the one gallery listed, when the overlay opens, the error occurs.) - Line 142 of gallery.js

1. Verify jQuery is loaded on the page, and only once. - Done
2. Verify jQuery is loaded before your scripts. - Done, jQuery in header, scripts in footer.
3. Try running in no-conflict mode - created other issues

The catch 22 of all this, is it's working on my homepage without any issue. So it's only this instance of the issue.

Anyone have advice for this illusive issue? I've spent hours on this one issue with no result... Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to call `prependTo` on a jquery object, not an `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the page with the error doesn't include the `<script>` with `id="img-wrapper-tmpl"` that you're looking for, but it does exist on the page that works correctly.

jQuery returns an empty array-like object when it's not found.

Comment: This worked like a charm, I was missing the template included in the header of the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your offending line:

```
$('#img-wrapper-tmpl').tmpl( {itemsCount : itemsCount} ).prependTo( $rgGallery );
```

Sounds like you are returning a non-jQuery object and trying to perform an operation on it.

I would suggest doing a console.log() on the offending object to find out exactly `what` you are getting back. And go from there.

Comment: On further reading, you are returning an array. Make sure that you return a jQuery object in order to use jQuery functions on it!

Comment: Have any idea why this is functioning as intended on the home though? Also, how would I best go about resolving this?

Comment: My guess is that on the home page, it is properly returning a jQuery object. Can you provide a link to a working page?

Comment: Dang it, sorry about the local link, should be http://sandboxdewsly.com and then Galleries > Select a gallery